# Spring Boot Disable /error mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am creating an API with Spring Boot so wish to disable the `/error` mapping.

I have set the following props in application.properties:

```
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
spring.resources.add-mappings=false
```

However when I hit `/error` I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 03 Aug 2016 15:15:31 GMT
Connection: close

{"timestamp":1470237331487,"status":999,"error":"None","message":"No message available"}
```

**Required Result**

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Internal Server Error
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

Comment: which spring boot version is this question about?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can disable the  ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class})
public class SpringBootLauncher {
```

Or through Spring Boot's application.yml/properties:

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration
```

If this is not an option for you, you may also extend Spring's ErrorController  with your own implementation:

```
@RestController
public class MyErrorController implements ErrorController {

    private static final String ERROR_MAPPING = "/error";

    @RequestMapping(value = ERROR_MAPPING)
    public ResponseEntity<String> error() {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return ERROR_MAPPING;
    }
```

**Note:** Use *one* of the above techniques (disabled auto-configuration or implement the error-controller). Both together **will not work**, as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Yeah I did this exact thing it's just annoying! Wonder if there's a way to remove the binding without doing this

Comment: annotation worked for me but entry in yml file was not working.

Comment: @Chinmay The yml entry does not work for you, because the Java package of the excluded class is invalid in the answer. It should be `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration`. OP, please accept the edit to the answer.

Comment: Note that when excluding `ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration`, you are, just as the docs say, excluding specific auto-configuration classes such that they will *never* be applied. Emphasis on ***never***! What this means is, whether or not you have a custom implementation of `ErrorController`, **it will be completely ignored**, and Spring is forced to return the error in its built-in manner, possibly including sensitive implementation details. E.g. when accessing the `/error` resource externally, the response includes a circular view path error with its entire Java stack-trace.

Answer (score 7):

Attributes should be specified via @SpringBootApplication. Example in Kotlin:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = [ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration::class])
class SpringBootLauncher {
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was with web resources referenced in the header of the login page. Specifically, css was referenced in the header, but did not actually exist in the project.

What might also be helpful, in my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` implementation I commented out the body of `configure(WebSecurity web)` first, then on trying to login, instead of displaying the above error json my browser's address bar would display the url to the resource causing the problem.

Comment: I don't think this answer related to the question at all.