# Spring boot do not change HTTP code in case of exception

Tags: spring, exception, spring-security, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-401

I have trouble controlling the HTTP response code of my Spring Boot Rest server. The controller advice change the header www-authenticate but I keep getting 404 not found (tested using Postman).

Here is my code (made to generate 401 all the time).

The Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
   public SecurityConfig()
   {
      super(false);
   }

   @Override
   protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception
   {
      return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList((AuthenticationProvider) new CustomAuthenticationProvider()));
   }

   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
   {
      http.httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(new MyAuthenticationEntryPoint());
      http.httpBasic()
            .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasAuthority("USER")
            .and().csrf().disable();
   }
}
```

The controller advice to indicate what to do in case of exception (actually trigger according to my console and the WWW-Authenticate value):

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint
{
   @Override
   public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException)
         throws IOException, ServletException
   {
      System.out.println("there");
      response.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Unauthorized test");
      response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, authException.getMessage());
   }
}
```

The authentication provider that will always throw a BadCredentialsException.

```
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider
{
   public CustomAuthenticationProvider()
   {
   }

   @Override
   public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
      throw new BadCredentialsException("Bad credentials exception"); 
   }

   @Override
   public boolean supports(Class<?> pClass)
   {
      return (pClass == UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
   }
}
```

Any idea what I did wrong?

Stacktrace:

```
..57,398 [DEBUG](o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet) - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing POST request for [/error]
..57,399 [TRACE](o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet) - Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping@1d9af731] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
..57,401 [TRACE](o.s.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping) - No handler mapping found for [/error]
..57,401 [TRACE](o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet) - Testing handler map [springfox.documentation.spring.web.PropertySourcedRequestMappingHandlerMapping@445058e8] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
..57,404 [TRACE](o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet) - Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping@5423a17] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
..57,405 [DEBUG](o.s.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping) - Looking up handler method for path /error
..57,412 [DEBUG](o.s.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping) - Did not find handler method for [/error]
..57,412 [TRACE](o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet) - Testing handler map [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WelcomePageHandlerMapping@347b370c] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
..57,413 [TRACE](o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet) - Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping@356fa0d1] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
..57,413 [TRACE](o.s.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping) - No handler mapping found for [/error]
..57,413 [TRACE](o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet) - Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping@31533eb1] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
..57,413 [DEBUG](o.s.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping) - Matching patterns for request [/error] are [/**]
..57,414 [DEBUG](o.s.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping) - URI Template variables for request [/error] are {}
..57,416 [DEBUG](o.s.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping) - Mapping [/error] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[ServletContext resource [/], class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@3c6fb501]]] and 1 interceptor
..57,418 [TRACE](o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet) - Testing handler adapter [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter@7ecb9e17]
..57,418 [TRACE](o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet) - Testing handler adapter [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter@4dac40b]
..57,427 [TRACE](o.s.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler) - Applying "invalid path" checks to path: error
..57,429 [TRACE](o.s.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver) - Resolving resource for request path "error"
..57,429 [TRACE](o.s.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver) - Checking location: ServletContext resource [/]
..57,429 [TRACE](o.s.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver) - No match for location: ServletContext resource [/]
..57,429 [TRACE](o.s.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver) - Checking location: class path resource [META-INF/resources/]
..57,430 [TRACE](o.s.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver) - No match for location: class path resource [META-INF/resources/]
..57,430 [TRACE](o.s.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver) - Checking location: class path resource [resources/]
..57,431 [TRACE](o.s.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver) - No match for location: class path resource [resources/]
..57,431 [TRACE](o.s.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver) - Checking location: class path resource [static/]
..57,432 [TRACE](o.s.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver) - No match for location: class path resource [static/]
..57,432 [TRACE](o.s.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver) - Checking location: class path resource [public/]
..57,432 [TRACE](o.s.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver) - No match for location: class path resource [public/]
..57,432 [TRACE](o.s.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler) - No matching resource found - returning 404
..57,432 [DEBUG](o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet) - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
..57,432 [TRACE](o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet) - Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@268be1ed
..57,432 [DEBUG](o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet) - Successfully completed request
..57,433 [TRACE](o.s.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext) - Publishing event in org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@40ef3420: ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/error]; client=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]; method=[POST]; servlet=[dispatcherServlet]; session=[null]; user=[null]; time=[37ms]; status=[OK]
..57,433 [DEBUG](o.s.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory) - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'delegatingApplicationListener'
```

Comment: Is spring trying to find the `/error` 'whitelabel' page? Try setting this property: `server.error.whitelabel.enabled = false`

Comment: I think you are right about the server trying to find some error mapping. However the property had no effect.I added stacktrace, I hope it will inspire/talk to someone.

Comment: Try the annotation method for removing `/error` given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38749728/1763035). I seem to remember having this problem myself. It's annoying, `/error` is a servlet hangover that has no place in a REST server. it should be easier to get rid of it.

Comment: It works with the annotation, thanks a lot for your help.