# Spring Security antMatchers being ignored or overridden

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

Spring Security 5.x here. I have the following security configuration:

```
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
@Slf4j
public class ApiSecurityConfig {

    private boolean securityDebug;


    @Autowired
    public ApiSecurityConfig(
            @Value("${spring.security.debug:false}") boolean securityDebug) {
        this.securityDebug = securityDebug;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

        log.info("configuring security...");

        // enable CSRF
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable();

        // add CORS filter
        httpSecurity.cors();

        // add anonoymous/permitted paths (that is: what paths are allowed to bypass authentication)
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/v1/alerts").permitAll()

                // restrict all other paths and set them to authenticated
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

httpSecurity.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        return httpSecurity.build();

    }

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web.debug(securityDebug)
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/img/**", "/lib/**", "/favicon.ico");
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {

        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();

        corsConfiguration.setAllowedOriginPatterns(List.of("*"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        corsConfigurationSource.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);

        return corsConfigurationSource;

    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler(RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy) {

        DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler();
        expressionHandler.setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy);
        return expressionHandler;

    }

}
```

When I run a curl on that GET `/v1/alerts` endpoint, I get 401s:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:8080/v1/alerts

HTTP/1.1 401 
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Realm"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 12 Oct 2023 17:49:13 GMT
```

In the Spring Security debug output I get:

```
13:52:58.212 [main] INFO  i.b.e.ws.MyServiceMonoServiceApp - Started MyServiceMonoServiceApp in 6.272 seconds (JVM running for 6.541)
13:52:58.236 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.a.ApplicationAvailabilityBean - Application availability state LivenessState changed to CORRECT
13:52:58.237 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.a.ApplicationAvailabilityBean - Application availability state ReadinessState changed to ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC
13:53:06.602 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
13:53:06.602 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
13:53:06.602 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver
13:53:06.602 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Detected AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver
13:53:06.602 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Detected FixedThemeResolver
13:53:06.605 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@7db097a6
13:53:06.605 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@4d53d85e
13:53:06.605 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
13:53:06.605 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed initialization in 3 ms
13:53:06.617 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Securing GET /v1/alerts
13:53:06.619 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
13:53:06.625 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped to io.myorg.MyService.ws.alerts.AlertController#getAlertStatus()
13:53:06.627 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
13:53:06.631 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Failed to authorize filter invocation [GET /v1/alerts] with attributes [authenticated]
13:53:06.631 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint - Trying to match using And [Not [RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]], MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.HeaderContentNegotiationStrategy@553779ba, matchingMediaTypes=[application/xhtml+xml, image/*, text/html, text/plain], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]]
13:53:06.631 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint - Trying to match using Or [RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest], And [Not [MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.HeaderContentNegotiationStrategy@3c2955f6, matchingMediaTypes=[text/html], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[]]], MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.HeaderContentNegotiationStrategy@3c2955f6, matchingMediaTypes=[application/atom+xml, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, application/json, application/octet-stream, application/xml, multipart/form-data, text/xml], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]], MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.HeaderContentNegotiationStrategy@3c2955f6, matchingMediaTypes=[*/*], useEquals=true, ignoredMediaTypes=[]]]
13:53:06.631 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint - Match found! Executing org.springframework.security.web.authentication.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint@5bb911c1
13:53:06.631 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint - Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]
13:53:06.631 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint - No match found. Using default entry point org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint@20ffa494
13:53:06.632 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - Did not store empty SecurityContext
13:53:06.632 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - Did not store empty SecurityContext
13:53:06.632 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
13:53:06.640 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Securing GET /error
13:53:06.640 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
13:53:06.640 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
13:53:06.640 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Secured GET /error
13:53:06.645 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator - filter invocation [/error] denied for AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:73)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator.isAllowed(DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator.isAllowed(DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator.java:67)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.ErrorPageSecurityFilter.isAllowed(ErrorPageSecurityFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.ErrorPageSecurityFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageSecurityFilter.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.ErrorPageSecurityFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageSecurityFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:237)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:223)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:219)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:711)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:385)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:313)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:403)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:249)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1732)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
13:53:06.645 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - Did not store anonymous SecurityContext
13:53:06.645 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - Did not store anonymous SecurityContext
13:53:06.645 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
```

**Any idea where I'm going awry?**

Comment: The log is clear: *Failed to authorize filter invocation [GET /v1/alerts] with attributes [authenticated]* So you have to be logged in, if you want to access this endpoint.

Comment: OK clearly I want `GET /v1/alerts` to be public/non-authenticated, what would I need to change? I'm 99% sure I have the antMatchers configured correctly.

Comment: Is this log line in your logs? *log.info("configuring security...");* At least with Spring Security 6 you need to add `@Configuration` on you class. Maybe it is not neccessary with Spring Security 5. I can't remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your Controller was actually called but an error occurred and Spring MVC routed it to **/error**. Then Spring Security tries to secure the **/error** as well but denies it since you have no authentication. So your client (curl) gets a 401.
If you want to be sure add some logs in your Controller or run in debug and see if your code is called.

To disable the internal redirect to /error see [Spring Boot Disable /error mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38747548/spring-boot-disable-error-mapping)

Comment: Yes I can verify the controller endpoint is called, I just can't find where the error is coming from, and why Spring would try to route the user to `/error`.

Comment: Please see here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38747548/spring-boot-disable-error-mapping